# Android emulator 4.2.2 not showing add widget option in lock screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, widget, lockscreen

In newer android versions you can add a widget to the homescreen AND the lock-screen. To be able to test this during development it would be good to be able to add these to the emulator-lock-screen as well.

This should be possible, but it just doesn't seem to work in my emulator version (runnin android 4.2.2

The version should be high enough to support this, so what could be the cause

Comment: Please restrict your questions to programming issues. StackOverflow is not intended to provide end user support.

Comment: you might require adt for this

Comment: Can you provide me any link, where I can get help for it

Comment: I disagree with the conclusions reached here by MarsAtomic, Gilles, tstenner etc. This sounds like a real question to me, if not the best example of grammar. I'm experiencing the same problem and I have the same question. Also it's insulting to belittle the question asker by categorizing their question as "end-user support". Developers need to test their software, and lock screen widgets need to be tested on the emulator if a developer can't affort to buy the latest phone model to test Android 4.2.2 issues.

Comment: Alright folks I found the cause and a solution! Only took all day. Turns out rev 2 of the API level 17 (4.2.2) emulator ARM system image is broken, adding widgets to the lock screen isn't possible. However the rev 1 system image works! You'll have to manually downgrade, zip file is available here: http://dl.google.com/android/repository/sysimg_armv7a-17_r01.zip   
Put it in your Android SDK files under system-images/android-17

Comment: I'm hoping for some re-open love on this question so we can make this comment above an actual answer!

Comment: I still say this is a valid question, and @Georgie 's answer one that should be below in the answer section.

Comment: thanks Georgie it worked , you should have given it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mine is showing up. Go to your AVD and make sure that the device you created/are using is the correct version of Android that supports lock screen widgets. (4.2.2)

Comment: yes I have create my avd for 4.2.2 only.

Comment: When you launch the device you need to use the mouse to swipe down on the clock widget then scroll to the left.

Comment: This works on rev 1 of the 4.2.2 system image but not rev 2, see my comment above for solution/workaround.